# outlook subject breaks conversation topic thread

Tags: outlook

our company insists on prefixing every email from an outside source with "[External]".  This causes an issue when an outside person responds to an email.  Because "[External]" is prefixed to the subject, Outlook thinks is it a new subject and breaks the conversation thread. I created a macro-based rule for every incoming email. Essentially I want to strip out the "External", "RE" and "FW" so the base subject can be joined back together into a single conversation.   I would like someone to help me with the below code.  I have tried to modify the conversation topic and conversation index but it is not grouping the items together.

```
Sub FixSubject(oItem As Outlook.MailItem)
On Error Resume Next

Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application

Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mail = myolApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

Dim aText As Variant, i As Long
aText = Array("[EXTERNAL]", "RE:", "FW:", "Re:", "Fw:")

For i = 0 To UBound(aText)
    oItem.Subject = Replace(oItem.Subject, aText(i), "", , , vbTextCompare)
Next

oItem.Subject = Trim(oItem.Subject)

'set the Conversation topic to the modified Subject
oItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0070001E", oItem.Subject

'set the Conversation Idex to null (I heard that OUtlook will use the topic instead)
oItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00710102", Null

oItem.Save

Set myolApp = Nothing
Set oItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Format your code please.

Comment: General help, if not useful now will be in the future. Remove "On Error Resume Next" so you can fix errors. Use this only for a specific purpose, to bypass a known error, then turn it off immediately with On Error GoTo 0".